URL segment "undefined" when clicking on item in chart.js
I'm having trouble with Chart.js where clicking on a chart segment always redirects to an undefined value. I have a doughnut chart and want each segment to redirect to a specific URL based on the segment clicked. However, the redirection always leads to undefined.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
Blade Template (Laravel):
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('teknisiChart').getContext('2d');

            var chartData = {
                labels: ['4 Tahun', '2-3 Tahun', '1 Tahun', 'Under 1 Tahun'],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [
                        {{ $countMoreThan4Years }},
                        {{ $countBetween2and3Years }},
                        {{ $count1YearAgo }},
                        {{ $countLessThan1Year }}
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 68, 68, 0.8)',
                        'rgba(255, 209, 91, 0.8)',
                        'rgba(223, 250, 125, 0.8)',
                        'rgba(114, 247, 137, 0.8)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 3
                }]
            };

            var teknisiChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: chartData,
                options: {
                    onClick: function(evt, item) {
                        if (item.length > 0) {
                            var index = item[0].index;
                            console.log('Index:', index);
                            var category = ['more-than-4-years', '2-3-years', '1-year', 'under-1-year'][
                                index
                            ];
                            console.log('Category:', category);
                            window.location.href = `{{ url('/hardware') }}/${category}`;
                        }
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    plugins: {
                        tooltip: {
                            callbacks: {
                                label: function(tooltipItem) {
                                    return chartData.labels[tooltipItem.dataIndex] + ': ' + tooltipItem
                                        .formattedValue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

Controller Method (Laravel):
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\ItMasterHardware;

class HardwareController extends Controller
{
    public function show($ageCategory)
    {
        dd($ageCategory); // Debugging line
        $dateNow = Carbon::now();

        switch ($ageCategory) {
            case 'more-than-4-years':
                $dateLimit = $dateNow->copy()->subYears(4);
                $hardware = ItMasterHardware::where('tgl_beli', '<=', $dateLimit)->get();
                break;

            case '2-3-years':
                $dateLimitStart = $dateNow->copy()->subYears(3);
                $dateLimitEnd = $dateNow->copy()->subYears(2);
                $hardware = ItMasterHardware::whereBetween('tgl_beli', [$dateLimitStart, $dateLimitEnd])->get();
                break;

            case '1-year':
                $dateLimitStart = $dateNow->copy()->subYear();
                $dateLimitEnd = $dateNow->copy()->subYears(2);
                $hardware = ItMasterHardware::whereBetween('tgl_beli', [$dateLimitStart, $dateLimitEnd])->get();
                break;

            case 'under-1-year':
                $dateLimit = $dateNow->copy()->subYear();
                $hardware = ItMasterHardware::where('tgl_beli', '>=', $dateLimit)->get();
                break;

            default:
                abort(404);
        }

        return view('hardware.index', compact('hardware'));
    }
}


When I click on a segment in the doughnut chart, it redirects to a URL with undefined as part of the path. I am trying to use the segment index to determine which URL to redirect to, but the resulting URL is incorrect.
What I’ve tried:

Debugging with console.log to check the index and category values.
Ensuring that the @json Blade directive is correctly passing PHP variables to Javascript.
Checking for Javascript errors in the console.

How do I correctly pass the segment index from Chart.js to construct a URL?
Are there any issues with the provided code that might be causing undefined values?

after a quick look - what is the value console.log('Index:', index); outputs?

So, what exactly were the results when you debugged the onClick callback function? What happened, step by step? What values did you see? What URL resulted? We can't see the source data, and therefore can't run your code to understand what it would do based on your data. Please [edit] your post. Thankyou.
